When i boot into ubuntu my laptop boots to windows instead
my new laptop only has 4gb ram and windows uses 3.5gb on idle so i wanted to download a lighter os. I first downloaded xubuntu, i installed it and after it was installed and it says press enter to restart, i do it and it goes to windows.i tested this with ubuntu lts too and the same happens.In boot options ubuntu is first at boot order.what do i do to run it?

Open UEFI settings (how to do that depends on your laptop manufacturer - ask your favorite search engine for how to), and set Ubuntu as the default bootloader.

What brand/model laptop?  They have vendor specific quirks, like setting "Trust" on the efi files for Acer or renaming the bootloader for HP.

Its helpful if you're specific with details; you mention Ubuntu but don't mention which Ubuntu product (Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? as they use different installers), and also mention Xubuntu but again no release details. Ubuntu Desktop & Xubuntu use two different installers based on release/ISO used and you didn't specify what release you're using. You can also cause a bootloader to fail to install if ISO is written incorrectly (or in a format unsuited for your device) but you gave no clues as to how written either. Being specific with details may help us to help you.

This question is similar to: Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
